# JPane "paintComponent" can't be called without JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

My problem that I am having is that in this code, the line will not draw at all if I get rid of the JLabel from it. I tested it out and without the JLabel stuff with in it, the paintComponent(Graphics g) won't run at all. I want to know why this is and why JLabel effects the JPanel like this.

I have read online that sometime the paintComponent(Graphics g) might not run if it is in a infinite loop but i still don't understand how the JLabel would effect this trait.

I would guess that it might have to do something with the layout but i don't really understand how layout effects things like this

MouseAction Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class MouseAction extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mousePanel;
    private JLabel statusBar;
    private GraphicsPanel g;
    private int xS;
    private int yS;

    public MouseAction (){
        super("Mouse example");
        mousePanel = new JPanel();
        statusBar = new JLabel("Deafault");

        g = new GraphicsPanel(0,0,0,0);


        add(mousePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        MouseExploits handler = new MouseExploits();

        mousePanel.addMouseListener(handler);
        mousePanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);



    }

    private class MouseExploits extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){
            if(mouse.isMetaDown()){
                xS= mouse.getX();
                yS= mouse.getY();
            }
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouse){
            if(!(mouse.isMetaDown() || mouse.isAltDown())){

                g.updateCoordinates(mouse.getX(),mouse.getY(), xS,yS);
                add(g);
                System.out.printf("%d,%d\n",mouse.getX(),mouse.getY());
                statusBar.setText(String.format("%d,%d",mouse.getX(),mouse.getY()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GraphicsPanel class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int xS;
    private int yS;
    private Graphics dB;
    private Image dBImage;

    public graphics(int mouseX, int mouseY, int xSm, int ySm){
        x = mouseX;
        y = mouseY;
        xS=xSm;
        yS=ySm;
        //System.out.println("Breaks2");

    }

    public void updateCoordinates(int mouseX, int mouseY, int xSm, int ySm){
        x = mouseX;
        y = mouseY;
        xS=xSm;
        yS=ySm;
        //repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dBImage = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
        dB = dBImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dB);
        g.drawImage(dBImage,0,0,this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Breaks3");
        g.drawLine(xS,yS,x,y);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

MainProg class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MouseAction frameObj= new MouseAction ();
        frameObj.setSize(300,230);

        frameObj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameObj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code now contains double buffering and been revamped so the GraphicsPanel  doesn't instantiate multiple of time how ever the issue of not be able to remove JLabel without breaking the program continues.

EDIT 2: after some messing around with the window after removing the JLabel, It seems to only work when i dragged on the screen,resized the window and then drag on the screen again. So it would seem there is some jpanel layout error which some how gets fixed by the jlabel being there.

Comment: 1) Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Follow the Java conventions and don't make up your own. 2) Don't call you class "Graphics". There is already a class by that name in the JDK.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to Java and still getting used to it. I'll remember these rules for later files .

Comment: Start with this program. It will take you a couple of minutes to change it now, instead of later. If you want to post code for users of the forum, then make sure the code follow Java conventions which makes it easier for us to read the code.

Comment: It should be correct now (i hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem with your code is that you instanciate `graphics` at each `mouseDragged` event. This is weird and bad. You must only handle each `mouseDragged`, store the coordinates and call `repaint` on the single `graphics` instance created and added to the interface at the beginning. This will cause a refresh.

Second, the `paintComponent` should just make the drawings so you must use some kind of (1) double buffering (create a off-line `BufferedImage` and its associated `Graphics`, draw into it and use it in the refresh), (2) collection of `Point` caught in `mouseDragged` and use them to `drawPolyline` in the `paintComponent` method.

---

Third don't call `repaint()` inside `paintComponent`. This will unnecessarily triggers calls to `paintComponent` in a kind of never ending loop.

Fourthly don't create a double buffer each time `paint` is called. At each refresh you will create a new `Image`. Create it once, draw in it in your `mouseDragged`method and trigger from it a `repaint()`, then make a `drawImage` in `paintComponent`.

Comment: `I don't really understand what you mean by double buffer.` - you need to keep track of all the lines you want to draw. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do custom painting.

Comment: double buffering is a very well known technic in computer graphics, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html for example.

Comment: I was able to understand what he meant by double buffering after a while of thinking it. I understood what double buffering is (i guess i expressed it poorly) but i didn't understand why i would need it here since i was already clearing the JPanel by using the `super.paintComponent`. That is why i removed the original comment

Comment: Your panel can simply : clear its area (if you want) and paint the double buffer. When a mouse event is caught you just have to modify the double buffer and trigger and call `repaint()` on the panel.

Comment: (1+) In addition to the above: 1) get rid of the paint() method. There is no need to override paint. Custom painting should only be done in the paintComponent() method. 2) In the `updateCoordinates(...)` method you need to invoke repaint(). That is whenever you change the state of a component you need to repaint it. 3) get rid of the "mousePanel". It serves no purpose. Instead you add the "GraphicsPanel" to the frame and you add the mouse listeners to this panel as well.

Comment: 1) How else would i be able be able to double buffer the image if i don't override paint class
2)i accidentally comment it out by mistake, i'll update it now
3)i broke it up like this so i can later add more graphic material related methods and add more UI related methods into MousePanel class. I assume this would be a good reason to break it up like this.

Comment: @user2324198, `How else would i be able be able to double buffer the image if i don't override paint class` That code is not doing double buffereing. But you don't need to anyway since Swing is double buffered by default. The concept you are talking about is drawing to a BufferedImage and then paint the BufferedImage. I already gave you a working example showing how this is done. I see you haven't read the link yet!